# How to show text (not JRadioButton text) upon mouse hover JRadioButton

Tags: java, radio-button, jradiobutton, mousehover

Does anyone know how to show text upon mouse hover over radio button?

I tried setToolTipText but it doesn't work.

Codes for RadioButton

```
rdbtnPediatric = new JRadioButton("Pediatric");
    rdbtnPediatric.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            String departmentSelection = "Pediatric";

            ChangeBedControl cbcS = new ChangeBedControl();

            ArrayList<ChangeBed> bedList = new ArrayList<ChangeBed>();

            bedList = cbcS.processGetAvailBedsEdit(bedStatusF, departmentSelection);

            comboBoxAllocateBed.removeAllItems();

            for (int i = 0; i < bedList.size(); i++) {      
                comboBoxAllocateBed.addItem(bedList.get(i).getBedID());
            }

        }
    });
    department.add(rdbtnPediatric);
    rdbtnPediatric.setBounds(229, 219, 81, 25);
    rdbtnPediatric.setForeground(colour);
    contentPane.add(rdbtnPediatric);
```

Codes for Condition to display text upon hovering the radio button

```
    ChangeBedControl cbc8 = new ChangeBedControl();

    bedList = cbc8.processCountBedsAvailableDpt4();

    for (int i = 0; i < bedList.size(); i++) {

        bedsAvailPediatric = bedList.get(i).getRowCountAvail();

    }

    if (bedsAvailPediatric <= 3) {

        rdbtnPediatric.setForeground(Color.RED);
        //Show a text "bed count low."

    }
```

Full Codes for this class

```
package Boundary;


public class CreateBedForm extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField textFieldPatientID;
private JTextField textFieldPatientName;
private JComboBox comboBoxAllocateBed;
private JComboBox comboBoxDpt;
private String bedStatusF = "Available";
private String selectedDepartment = "";

private JRadioButton rdbtnCardiothoracic;
private JRadioButton rdbtnOncology;
private JRadioButton rdbtnOrthopaedic;
private JRadioButton rdbtnPediatric;

private int bedsAvailCardio;
private int bedsAvailOncology;
private int bedsAvailOrtho;
private int bedsAvailPediatric;

private Color colour = new Color(0, 204, 0);
private final ButtonGroup department = new ButtonGroup();

private String msgCA = "Beds are running out for Cardiothoracic Department!" + bedsAvailCardio + " beds left!";
private String msgON = "Beds are running out for Oncology Department!" + bedsAvailOncology + " beds left!";
private String msgOR = "Beds are running out for Orthopaedic Department!" + bedsAvailOrtho + " beds left!";
private String msgPE = "Beds are running out for Orthopaedic Department!" + bedsAvailPediatric + " beds left!";

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                CreateBedForm frame = new CreateBedForm("", "", "");
                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public CreateBedForm(String val1, String val2, String admissionID) {
    setTitle("Assign Bed");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 400);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblPatientId = new JLabel("Patient ID:");
    lblPatientId.setBounds(42, 52, 71, 16);
    contentPane.add(lblPatientId);

    JLabel lblPatientName = new JLabel("Patient Name:");
    lblPatientName.setBounds(42, 97, 96, 16);
    contentPane.add(lblPatientName);

    textFieldPatientID = new JTextField();
    textFieldPatientID.setEditable(false);
    textFieldPatientID.setBounds(138, 49, 116, 22);
    contentPane.add(textFieldPatientID);
    textFieldPatientID.setColumns(10);

    textFieldPatientName = new JTextField();
    textFieldPatientName.setEditable(false);
    textFieldPatientName.setBounds(138, 94, 116, 22);
    contentPane.add(textFieldPatientName);
    textFieldPatientName.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblAllocatedBed = new JLabel("Allocated Bed:");
    lblAllocatedBed.setBounds(42, 183, 96, 16);
    contentPane.add(lblAllocatedBed);

    comboBoxAllocateBed = new JComboBox();
    comboBoxAllocateBed.setBounds(138, 180, 71, 22);
    contentPane.add(comboBoxAllocateBed);

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Department:");
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(42, 142, 96, 16);
    contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);

    JButton btnAssignBed = new JButton("Assign Bed");
    btnAssignBed.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            //Adding

            String patientID = textFieldPatientID.getText();
            String patientName = textFieldPatientName.getText();

            String selectedDepartment = comboBoxDpt.getSelectedItem().toString();

            String selectedBed = comboBoxAllocateBed.getSelectedItem().toString();

            ChangeBed cb = new ChangeBed(selectedBed, selectedDepartment, patientID, patientName);

            ChangeBedControl cbc = new ChangeBedControl();

            cbc.processAssignBeds(cb, selectedBed);

            //Updating 

            bedStatusF = "Unavailable";

            ChangeBed cb2 = new ChangeBed(selectedBed, selectedDepartment, patientID, patientName);

            ChangeBedControl cbc2 = new ChangeBedControl();

            cbc2.processAssignBeds2(cb2, selectedBed, bedStatusF);

            dispose();

            File desktop = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "/Desktop"); 
            Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate());

            com.itextpdf.text.Font font1 = FontFactory.getFont("Verdana", 25, Font.BOLD);
            com.itextpdf.text.Font font2 = FontFactory.getFont("Verdana", 15, Font.BOLD);

            Paragraph p = new Paragraph(("Patient Admission Details"), font1);
            Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph(("Admission ID"), font2);
            Paragraph p2 = new Paragraph(("Patient ID"), font2);
            Paragraph p3 = new Paragraph(("Patient Name"), font2);
            Paragraph p4 = new Paragraph(("Date and Time Admitted"), font2);
            Paragraph p5 = new Paragraph(("Reason"), font2);
            Paragraph p6 = new Paragraph(("Date and Time Discharged"), font2);

            Paragraph pp = new Paragraph(("Bed Allocation Details"), font1);    
            Paragraph p01 = new Paragraph(("Bed ID"), font2);
            Paragraph p02 = new Paragraph(("Department"), font2);

            try {

                PageSize.A4.rotate();

                PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(desktop + "/" + textFieldPatientName.getText() + " Admission.pdf"));
                document.open();

                document.add(p);

                PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(6);
                table.setWidthPercentage(102);

                PdfPCell cell1 = new PdfPCell();
                cell1.addElement(p1);

                PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell();
                cell2.addElement(p2);

                PdfPCell cell3 = new PdfPCell();
                cell3.addElement(p3);

                PdfPCell cell4 = new PdfPCell();
                cell4.addElement(p4);

                PdfPCell cell5 = new PdfPCell();
                cell5.addElement(p5);

                PdfPCell cell6 = new PdfPCell();
                cell6.addElement(p6);

                AdmissionInfoControl aic1 = new AdmissionInfoControl();

                ArrayList<AdmissionInfo> admissionList = new ArrayList<AdmissionInfo>();

                admissionList = aic1.processGetAdmissionInfoView(admissionID);

                PdfPCell ell1;
                PdfPCell ell2;
                PdfPCell ell3;
                PdfPCell ell4;
                PdfPCell ell5;
                PdfPCell ell6;

                for (int i = 0; i < admissionList.size(); i++) {

                    ell1 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(admissionList.get(i).getAdmissionID()));
                    ell2 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(admissionList.get(i).getPatientID()));
                    ell3 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(admissionList.get(i).getPatientName()));
                    ell4 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(admissionList.get(i).getDateAdmitted()));
                    ell5 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(admissionList.get(i).getReason()));                       
                    ell6 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(admissionList.get(i).getDateDischarged()));

                    table.setSpacingBefore(30f);
                    table.addCell(cell1);
                    table.addCell(cell2);
                    table.addCell(cell3);
                    table.addCell(cell4);
                    table.addCell(cell5);
                    table.addCell(cell6);

                    table.addCell(ell1);
                    table.addCell(ell2);
                    table.addCell(ell3);
                    table.addCell(ell4);
                    table.addCell(ell5);
                    table.addCell(ell6);

                }               

                document.add(table);

                document.add(pp);

                PdfPTable table2 = new PdfPTable(2);

                table2.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);

                table2.setWidthPercentage(50);

                PdfPCell cell01 = new PdfPCell();
                cell01.addElement(p01);

                PdfPCell cell02 = new PdfPCell();
                cell02.addElement(p02);

                ArrayList<ChangeBed> bedList = new ArrayList<ChangeBed>();

                bedList = cbc.processGetBedsEdit(textFieldPatientID.getText());

                PdfPCell ell01;
                PdfPCell ell02;

                for (int i = 0; i < bedList.size(); i++) {

                    ell01 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(bedList.get(i).getBedID()));
                    ell02 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(bedList.get(i).getDepartment()));

                    table2.setSpacingBefore(30f);
                    table2.addCell(cell01);
                    table2.addCell(cell02);

                    table2.addCell(ell01);
                    table2.addCell(ell02);

                }

                document.add(table2);

                document.close();

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Admission PDF has been successfully created.");

            } catch (Exception ex) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: " + ex);

            }

        }
    });

    btnAssignBed.setBounds(288, 303, 116, 25);
    contentPane.add(btnAssignBed);

    comboBoxDpt = new JComboBox();
    comboBoxDpt.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"--Select Department--", "Cardiothoracic", "Oncology", "Orthopaedic", "Pediatric"}));
    comboBoxDpt.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            String departmentSelection = comboBoxDpt.getSelectedItem().toString();

            ChangeBedControl cbcS = new ChangeBedControl();

            ArrayList<ChangeBed> bedList = new ArrayList<ChangeBed>();

            bedList = cbcS.processGetAvailBedsEdit(bedStatusF, departmentSelection);

            comboBoxAllocateBed.removeAllItems();

            for (int i = 0; i < bedList.size(); i++) {      
                comboBoxAllocateBed.addItem(bedList.get(i).getBedID());
            }

        }
    });
    comboBoxDpt.setBounds(62, 256, 153, 22);
    contentPane.add(comboBoxDpt);

    rdbtnCardiothoracic = new JRadioButton("Cardiothoracic");
    rdbtnCardiothoracic.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            String departmentSelection = "Cardiothoracic";

            ChangeBedControl cbcS = new ChangeBedControl();

            ArrayList<ChangeBed> bedList = new ArrayList<ChangeBed>();

            bedList = cbcS.processGetAvailBedsEdit(bedStatusF, departmentSelection);

            comboBoxAllocateBed.removeAllItems();

            for (int i = 0; i < bedList.size(); i++) {      
                comboBoxAllocateBed.addItem(bedList.get(i).getBedID());
            }

        }
    });
    department.add(rdbtnCardiothoracic);
    rdbtnCardiothoracic.setBounds(138, 138, 111, 25);
    rdbtnCardiothoracic.setForeground(colour);
    contentPane.add(rdbtnCardiothoracic);

    rdbtnOncology = new JRadioButton("Oncology");
    rdbtnOncology.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            String departmentSelection = "Oncology";

            ChangeBedControl cbcS = new ChangeBedControl();

            ArrayList<ChangeBed> bedList = new ArrayList<ChangeBed>();

            bedList = cbcS.processGetAvailBedsEdit(bedStatusF, departmentSelection);

            comboBoxAllocateBed.removeAllItems();

            for (int i = 0; i < bedList.size(); i++) {      
                comboBoxAllocateBed.addItem(bedList.get(i).getBedID());
            }

        }
    });
    department.add(rdbtnOncology);
    rdbtnOncology.setBounds(253, 138, 81, 25);
    rdbtnOncology.setForeground(colour);
    contentPane.add(rdbtnOncology);

    rdbtnOrthopaedic = new JRadioButton("Orthopaedic");
    rdbtnOrthopaedic.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            String departmentSelection = "Orthopaedic";

            ChangeBedControl cbcS = new ChangeBedControl();

            ArrayList<ChangeBed> bedList = new ArrayList<ChangeBed>();

            bedList = cbcS.processGetAvailBedsEdit(bedStatusF, departmentSelection);

            comboBoxAllocateBed.removeAllItems();

            for (int i = 0; i < bedList.size(); i++) {      
                comboBoxAllocateBed.addItem(bedList.get(i).getBedID());
            }

        }
    });
    department.add(rdbtnOrthopaedic);
    rdbtnOrthopaedic.setBounds(229, 179, 127, 25);
    rdbtnOrthopaedic.setForeground(colour);
    contentPane.add(rdbtnOrthopaedic);

    rdbtnPediatric = new JRadioButton("Pediatric");
    rdbtnPediatric.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            String departmentSelection = "Pediatric";

            ChangeBedControl cbcS = new ChangeBedControl();

            ArrayList<ChangeBed> bedList = new ArrayList<ChangeBed>();

            bedList = cbcS.processGetAvailBedsEdit(bedStatusF, departmentSelection);

            comboBoxAllocateBed.removeAllItems();

            for (int i = 0; i < bedList.size(); i++) {      
                comboBoxAllocateBed.addItem(bedList.get(i).getBedID());
            }

        }
    });
    department.add(rdbtnPediatric);
    rdbtnPediatric.setBounds(229, 219, 81, 25);
    rdbtnPediatric.setForeground(colour);
    contentPane.add(rdbtnPediatric);

    /*comboBoxDpt = new JComboBox(departments);

    ComboBoxRenderer renderer = new ComboBoxRenderer(comboBoxDpt);

    renderer.setColorsForMain(colorsForMain);
    renderer.setDepartments(departments);

    comboBoxDpt.setRenderer(renderer);*/

    ChangeBedControl cbc = new ChangeBedControl();

    ArrayList<AdmissionInfo> admissionList = new ArrayList<AdmissionInfo>();

    admissionList = cbc.processGetChangeBedCreate(val1, val2);

    for (int i = 0; i < admissionList.size(); i++) {

        textFieldPatientID.setText(admissionList.get(i).getPatientID());

        textFieldPatientName.setText(admissionList.get(i).getPatientName());

    }

    //=============Distinct Feature=============
    ArrayList<ChangeBed> bedList = new ArrayList<ChangeBed>();

    /*int selectedIndex = comboBoxDpt.getSelectedIndex() ;

    String departmentComboBox;*/

    ChangeBedControl cbc2 = new ChangeBedControl();

    bedList = cbc2.processCountBedsAvailableDpt1();

    for (int i = 0; i < bedList.size(); i++) {

        bedsAvailCardio = bedList.get(i).getRowCountAvail();

    }

    if (bedsAvailCardio <= 3) {

        rdbtnCardiothoracic.setForeground(Color.RED);   

    }

    ChangeBedControl cbc4 = new ChangeBedControl();

    bedList = cbc4.processCountBedsAvailableDpt2();

    for (int i = 0; i < bedList.size(); i++) {

        bedsAvailOncology = bedList.get(i).getRowCountAvail();

    }

    if (bedsAvailOncology <= 3) {

        rdbtnOncology.setForeground(Color.RED);     

    }

    ChangeBedControl cbc6 = new ChangeBedControl();

    bedList = cbc6.processCountBedsAvailableDpt3();

    for (int i = 0; i < bedList.size(); i++) {

        bedsAvailOrtho = bedList.get(i).getRowCountAvail();

    }

    if (bedsAvailOrtho <= 3) {

        rdbtnOrthopaedic.setForeground(Color.RED);

    }

    ChangeBedControl cbc8 = new ChangeBedControl();

    bedList = cbc8.processCountBedsAvailableDpt4();

    for (int i = 0; i < bedList.size(); i++) {

        bedsAvailPediatric = bedList.get(i).getRowCountAvail();

    }

    if (bedsAvailPediatric <= 3) {

        rdbtnPediatric.setForeground(Color.RED);
        //Show a text "bed count low."

    }


}
```

}

Comment: I'd suggest you to try to add a `mouseMotionListener`, like `rdbtnPediatric.addMouseMotionListener(MouseMotionListener l)` and implement  the method `mouseMoved`, which seems to behave as a hover...

Comment: I have tried that Rucsi but the tooltiptext doesn't appear.

Comment: Nvm Rucsi i got it thanks!!

Comment: Anyway, this link could help you : http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-custom-mouse-cursor-xy-coordinates-position

Comment: This is far from a minimal example. Please edit your question and include only the very necessary parts.

Comment: Thanks Rucsi, will save for future reference!